# Conflicto de tipos de operandos: time es incompatible con numeric sqlserver

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedure

Estoy realizando un procedimiento almacenado de agregar una venta pero no tengo este error **Conflicto de tipos de operandos: time es incompatible con numeric**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Este Codigo es el mismo

```
CREATE procedure agregarventa(

@idusuario int,
@idcliente int,
@fecha date,
@total decimal (18,2)
)

as 

begin

insert into venta

values (@idusuario,@idcliente,@fecha,@total)

select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Id

end
```

### Este Codigo es el mismo solo que ingresa mas cosas y contiene el error ya mencionada : Conflicto de tipos de operandos: time es incompatible con numeric

```
Create procedure agregarventa(

@Idcliente int,
@Idusuario int,
@fechafactura date,
@Horafactura time,
@tipopago nvarchar(50),
@Subtotal numeric (18,2),
@Descuento numeric (18,2),
@totalcordobas numeric(18,2),
@totaldolares numeric(18,2)
)

as 

begin

insert into venta 

values 

(@Idcliente,@Idusuario,@fechafactura,@Horafactura,@tipopago,@Subtotal,@Descuento,@totalcordobas,@totaldolares)

select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id

end
```

Comment: es en postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible que esté mal el orden en que la tabla tiene sus columnas y estés insertando un valor time en un numeric, para mayor seguridad agrega los nombres de las columnas seguido de el nombre de la tabla.

```
INSERT INTO 
venta(Idcliente, Idusuario, fechafactura, Horafactura, tipopago, Subtotal, Descuento, totalcordobas, totaldolares) 
VALUES(@Idcliente,@Idusuario,@fechafactura,@Horafactura,@tipopago,@Subtotal,@Descuento,@totalcordobas,@totaldolares).
```

Comparte la estructura de la tabla, para que pueda ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ya ingrese la tabla

Comment: Si es el problema que te comento, pon los nombres de las columnas entre paréntesis justo después del nombre de la tabla y asegúrate que coincidan con el orden en el que estás ingresando los parámetros.

Comment: Gracias Amigo..

Comment: Seria bueno explicarle porque pasa esto. Al no ingresar los nombres de las columnas en el insert, la DB (la mayoria) toma por defecto para ingresar los datos el orden de creacion de los campos. Como vos estas ingresando los datos en desorden, la DB no sabe cual va en cada lugar, y pone las cosas en el mismo orden de carga